# How do I find a list of the friends who share their google latitude location with me?

Tags: android, google-latitude

I'm busy writing an application to run on an android device. How can I get a list of friends that have shared their google latitude location information with me?

I have found an example using the public location badge, but this means that the friend has to make their location visible to everyone, and I don't want them to have to do this. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [link which is the feature request](http://code.google.com/p/latitude-api/issues/detail?id=1) for being able to see the location of friends without having to use their public badge. And this is the link for [why it's a 'wont fix'](https://groups.google.com/group/google-latitude-api/browse_thread/thread/e7c354b0590d3b7e/d6a160371577de88?#d6a160371577de88).

Answer (score 0):

There's a REST API available at http://code.google.com/apis/latitude

Here's some sample code from Google, using with their Google APIs java wrapper:
http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/latitude-json-oauth-sample/instructions.html?r=default

Comment: I've gone through the examples and the API documentation and it seems that you can only get your own information, not that of your friends. This is why I was wondering if it is possible to get your friends' information.